# C++: Is it valid to omit a parameter value in a function call?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

When compiling VTK 7.0.0 from source using GCC 6, I came across the following build error:

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
>
> radioButton_Min->setGeometry(QRect(10, 20, , 17));

The code used to build fine with GCC 5 that came bundled with the previous Fedora version. I realize that this may be a mistake by the VTK authors, but given the fact that the code used to build, here are two questions:

- Is this code valid C++?
- Is this code valid for GCC and / or other compilers given some loose settings, while not being valid by the standard? At the moment my warning and error settings are pretty tight.

**Important edit:**

Just found out that this code has been generated with Qt UIC (interface compiler) that produces C++ code based on .ui interface definition files. Probably the previous version of UIC handled this differently. But, for me, the question still remains: Could you quote the standard to be positively sure this is illegal C++?

Comment: *"Is this code valid C++?"* No, as far as I can tell. I can't imagine how it could have possibly compiled, unless it ended up being `#ifdef`ed away.

Comment: `QRect(10, 20, , 17)` needs 4 arguments.

Comment: @Franck exactly, and I wonder how it is not being called this way! Maybe some compilers would accept this, though of course it may be a simple bug.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, there is [one possibility](https://godbolt.org/g/WE9PQB) for this code to be valid. I'm pretty sure that is not the case, though.

Comment: What file is that line in?  I don't find a line that looks remotely like that in VTK 7.0.0.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Generated by uic from Examples/GUI/Qt/FourPaneViewer/QtVTKRenderWindows.ui. Look in the build directory to find it.

Comment: It's valid if `QRect` is a macro.

Comment: Voted to close since "it's not about programming". Dear StackOverflow, what's going on with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 5.2.2 Function call
>
> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses
>   containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of
>   initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function.

Note that this only says that the list of parameters to a function call can be "possibly empty". Obviously. But otherwise each parameter in the list of parameters is an `initializer-clause`.

An `initializer-clause` is defined in `8.5 Initializers` as follows:

```
initializer-clause:
    assignment-expression
    braced-init-list
```

So, each parameter to a function call is either an `assignment-expression` or a `braced-init-list`.

A `braced-init-list` always begins, unsurprisingly, with a `{`:

```
braced-init-list:
   { initializer-list , opt }
   {}
```

That excludes that. So, in order for an individual parameter to a function call to possibly be empty, the `assignment-expression` must be able to resolve to an empty rule, in some way. Going down the rabbit hole:

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
    throw-expression
```

The `conditional-expression` leads further down the rabbit hole of arithmetical expressions:

```
conditional-expression:
  logical-or-expression
  logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

This cannot be empty. Resolving `logical-or-expression` further is going to get real old. The bottom line is that there's going to be an operator here, somewhere, so this cannot be empty.

```
assignment-operator: one of = *= /= %= += -= >>= <<=
```

This eliminates the second possible form of `assignment-expression` as being empty. It's guaranteed to have an operator.

That leaves `throw-expression`:

```
throw-expression:
    throw assignment-expression opt
```

This might seem bizarre, but section 15 defines that: "A throw-expression is of type void". This is just an expression of the type `void`. The bottom line is that this grammar rule cannot be empty, either.

This conclusively precludes the possibility of a parameter to a function call being empty. The grammar rules specified by the C++ standard preclude that.

Comment: The *throw-expression* begins with the keyword `throw`. So, no need to dwell on it beyond that :)

Comment: Correct, I was just commenting on unexpectedness of `throw` turning out to be an expression, rather than a statement.

Comment: Sam, that's insane =] Of course this is the accepted answer but let's leave it open for a while more. Bet you enjoy answering questions about the standard.

Comment: OK, I'm accepting this now before the question gets closed, the amount of flags and d-votes is steadily increasing..

Comment: You have six upvotes and three downvotes. Nothing to worry about. Most bad questions typically get closed within an hour.

Comment: I also have two flags. Dunno, must be out of luck, most of the Q's I've been asking recently get d-vote and close flags, despite being, well, thoughtful, in my opinion.

Comment: Flags are irrelevant until the question is flagged five times, then it is closed. For truly bad questions this happens within an hour. It is unlikely that this question will be closed. The C++ topic has very low tolerance for poor questions. Very few questions come out without at least one close flag. Tough crowd.